# Equivalence between two statements

Tags: linear-algebra

Define a vector subspace $V=\{P|P^T=-P\}$. Let linear transformation $T$ to be defined as $T_A (M)=AM+MA$ where $A$ is any 3 by 3 symmetric matrix. It can be proved that $T_A(M)∈V$ for any $M∈V$.

The question is:
Show that the following are equivalent:
(i) $T_A:V→V$ is an isomorphism
(ii) The trace $tr(A)$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$.

1. I don't know how to prove that the trace $tr(A)$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$
2. I don't know how to build a connection between (i) and (ii).

Comment: You describe $V$ as a "subspace" without mentioning of what enclosing space, perhaps $\mathbb R^{3\times 3} $?  The property that defines $$ is called *antisymmetric*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is a question where I think it is easier to prove that $T_A$ is not an isomorphism if and only if $tr(A)$ is an eigenvalue of A.

As $T_A: V\to V$, it is an isomorphism if and only if it is injective. So we want to show $T_A$ is not injective if and only if $tr(A)$ is an eigenvalue of A.

Let $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ be the eigenvalues of A with corresponding eigenvectors $v_i$. As $A$ is real and symmetric, these all exist.

Now if $T_A(M)=T_A(N)$, then $T_A(M)v_i=T_A(N)v_i$, which, using that $v_i$ is an eigenvector, tells us that
$$(A+\lambda_iI)(M-N)v_i=0$$
and so $-\lambda_i$ is an eigenvector. Thus, as sets
$$\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3\}=\{-\lambda_1,-\lambda_2,-\lambda_3\}$$

Now trace is the sum of the eigenvalues, so this tells us that $tr(A)=0$ and that one of the eigenvalues must be 0 as well, giving one direction of the implication.

Now consider what happens if $tr(A)$ is an eigenvalue. Can you show $T_A$ is not injective? Not surjective?

Suppose $\lambda_1=tr(A)$ is an eigenvalue. Then as $tr(A)=\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3=tr(A)$, so $\lambda_2=-\lambda_3$.

Now, as $A$ is real and symmetric, there exists orthogonal $P$ i.e. $PP^T=I$ such that $P^TAP$ is diagonal. Noting that, if $M^T=-M$, them $(P^TMP)^T=-P^TMP$, we can assume $A$ is diagonal

(Consider $P^TT_A(M)P=P^TAPP^TMP+P^TMPP^TAP$)

Hence, $$T_A(M)=diag(tr(A),\lambda,-\lambda)M+Mdiag(tr(A),\lambda,-lambda)$$
and it is sufficient to find $M\neq 0, M\in V$ such that this is 0. $M$ with a 1 in the second row/third column, -1 in the third row/second column, and 0 everywhere else should work. Finding this $M$ was just a matter of solving $T_A(M)=0$ in terms of entries for a non-zero $M$.

Comment: Could you please explain more about how to show $_$ is not injective if $()$ is an eigenvalue?

Comment: I've edited my answer to expand on this